# CSS animation - revert on mouseout

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

I'm sure this must have been asked before and I've found related questions but I can't quite seem to crack this.

I have an element which receives a class and, on doing so, expands. Later, when that class is removed, it should revert (animate) back to its original width.

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#side-bar');
el.addEventListener('click', evt => el.classList.toggle('contracted'));
```

```css
#side-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  background: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#side-bar.contracted {
  animation: .5s side-bar-contract forwards;
}

#side-bar:not(.contracted) {
  animation: .5s side-bar-expand forwards;
}

@keyframes side-bar-expand {
  to {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

@keyframes side-bar-contract {
  to {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='side-bar' class='contracted'></div>
```

The expansion animation works fine. But the reversion animation doesn't happen; it just snaps back to its original properties, no anim.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqmc30r6/)

What am I doing wrong?

[ EDIT ]

OK I should obviously have mentioned why I'm not doing this with `transition`. This is part of a wider set of dependent animations which run in a sequence, one after another. My understanding is that this sort of chronologically non-trivial situation is better for `animation` rather than `transition`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:** (Removing the animation at the beginning)

```js
let init = 0,
    el = document.querySelector('#side-bar');

el.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (init < 1) {
        init++;
        el.classList.remove("init");
        el.classList.add('contracted');
    }
    el.classList.toggle('contracted');

});
```

```css
#side-bar {
 height: 100%;
 width: 75px;
 background: #d4653c;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 padding: .8rem;
}

#side-bar:not(.init) {
 animation: .5s side-bar-expand forwards;
}

#side-bar.contracted {
 animation: .5s side-bar-contract forwards;
}

@keyframes side-bar-expand {
 to {
  width: 350px;
 }
}

@keyframes side-bar-contract {
 from {
  width: 350px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id='side-bar' class='init'>Click me</div>
```

Just change `to` to `from` in `side-bar-contract`

```
@keyframes side-bar-expand { to { width: 350px; } }
@keyframes side-bar-contract { from { width: 350px; } }
```

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#side-bar');
el.addEventListener('click', evt => el.classList.toggle('contracted'));
```

```css
#side-bar {
 height: 100%;
 width: 75px;
 background: #d4653c;
 position: fixed;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 padding: .8rem;
}

#side-bar:not(.contracted) {
 animation: .5s side-bar-expand forwards;
}

#side-bar.contracted {
 animation: .5s side-bar-contract forwards;
}

@keyframes side-bar-expand {
 to {
  width: 350px;
 }
}

@keyframes side-bar-contract {
 from {
  width: 350px;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id='side-bar' class='contracted'>Click me</div>
```

Comment: I agree. I would also add an initial extra class, like 'initial' that has `animation: none`, and remove on click; just so that the animation doesn't play when the page is initially loaded.

Comment: Good shout, @maurojflores - that's the problem I'm currently facing, and your suggestion will stop that. Thanks, everyone.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use a transition animation:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#side-bar');
el.addEventListener('click', evt => el.classList.toggle('contracted'));
```

```css
#side-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 350px;                         /* have width at 350px when not contracted */
  background: #d4653c;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: .8rem;
  transition: width .5s;   /* animate the width */
}

#side-bar.contracted {
  width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div id='side-bar' class='contracted'>Click me</div>
```

If you need to use keyframes then you need to start the second one off at 350px - you start it at 75 to 75 which is why it doesn't animate:

```js
let el = document.querySelector('#side-bar');
el.addEventListener('click', evt => el.classList.toggle('contracted'));
```

```css
#side-bar {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75px;
  background: #d4653c;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: .8rem;
}

#side-bar:not(.contracted) {
  animation: .5s side-bar-expand forwards;
}

#side-bar.contracted {
  animation: .5s side-bar-contract forwards;
}

@keyframes side-bar-expand {
  to {
    width: 350px;
  }
}

@keyframes side-bar-contract {
  0% {
    width: 350px;
  }
  100% {
    width: 75px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id='side-bar' class='contracted'>Click me</div>
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using animation rather than transition because of other, child elements which should fade in after, i.e. there's a chronology at play here. And my understanding is transitions can't really handle multi-element, chronologically non-trivial cases like that (could be wrong.)

Comment: Ah ok, see edit - you need to start the second animation from 350px (it currently starts at 75px as that is the width you gave to sidebar (even though the other animation ends at 350px, I think it takes the initial value rather than what the other animation has ended on)

Comment: Interesting - never occured to me to have an animation with only a from. Thanks a lot.

Comment: actually the from answer by gildas is better because you don't get the initial closing animation

Comment: Very honest of you, tick given to the other answer. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

First, I would recommend you do this with hover styles and css `transition` instead of an animation for something as simple as animating a single property.

```
.class {
  width: 400px;
  transition: width 1500ms ease-in-out;
}

.class:hover {
  width: 100px;
}
```

CSS transition will actually stop part way through the transition and reverse to the initial size for you.

Second, I would recommend that you do not animate or transition the `width` property in CSS. [Here's a great article about what properties you should avoid animating](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).

If you need to delay a transition from happening on other elements, you can use the `transition-delay` property. This property can also be applied in hover effects... including with hover effects on parent elements. So you may potentially have multiple hover effects in play at a given time to accomplish your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned why I'm using animation rather than transition. Please see edit.

Comment: Ah. Saw your comment. I updated my answer for you. Your other transitions can technically be run with `transition-delay`. That way they do not run for however long you need your delay to be.

Comment: Thank you, I will study your answer. Re: transition delay, the problem then is when you want to reverse the transitions. Say I hover on element A and element B then fades in once A has finished. I don't think there's a way to reverse this order when reverting, right? Hence I went with animation.

Comment: Yes. When you move your mouse to another area, you can also change transition delays on hover if you need to. And transitions automatically reverse for you.

However, based on the interaction you described, a hover might not actually be the best UX in this case. A user will be confused by hovering and not seeing anything show up. So sticking with animations where you have control in code is probably a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My real situation is click-basd, not hover (that was just a contrived example in my comment for why I'd chosen animation over transition.) Thanks all the same and +1.